# Slidedown menu with sliding down rest menu

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need slide down multiple-level vertical menu with Headings of sections of the catalog

### I use bootstrap btn-group-vertical:

```
<?php
if($slider_enabled){
?>

<div class='clearfix'></div>
<div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class='index-slider1'>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical1 open" role="group" aria-label="Vertical">
<?php
    $arrarr1[0] = 0;
    $arrarr2 = array();
    $categories1 = $categories;
    $ccount=0; $ccount1=0; $ccount2=0; $clevel=0;
    while($ccount1!=count($categories)) {
        $ccount2++;
        if(count($categories1[$ccount]["childs"])>0) {
            ?>
            <div class="btn-group-vertical1 open" role="group" aria-label="Vertical">
            <button id="btnGroupVerticalDrop_<?=($ccount2.".".$ccount1.".".$clevel.".".$ccount);?>" type="button" class="btn btn-default1 dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <?php
                    $tcnt = -1;
                    while(++$tcnt<=$clevel) {
                        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }
                    echo $categories1[$ccount]["name"];
                ?>
                <span class="caret right1"></span>
            </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu1 drop" aria-labelledby="btnGroupVerticalDrop_<?=($ccount2.".".$ccount1.".".$clevel.".".$ccount);?>">
            <?php
            array_push($arrarr2, array($ccount, $categories1, $strcount));
            $categories1 = $categories1[$ccount]["childs"]; $ccount=-1;
            $clevel++;
            $strcount = substr($strcount, 0, strrpos($strcount, "."));
            ?>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default1" id="<?=($ccount2.".".$ccount1.".".$clevel.".".$ccount);?>">
                <?php
                $tcnt = -1;
                while(++$tcnt<$clevel) {
                    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
                echo $categories1[$ccount]["name"];
                ?>
            </button>
            <?php
        }
        while($ccount==(count($categories1)-1)) {
            $arrarr1 = array_pop($arrarr2);
            $strcount = $arrarr1[2]; $categories1 = $arrarr1[1]; $ccount = $arrarr1[0];
            $clevel--;
            ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        if(count($arrarr2)==0) {
            $ccount1++;
        }
        $ccount++;
    }
?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9"></div>
<?php
}
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".drop").click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

---

Issue: First level of menu is slide up and slide down but second level and so on is not response. The purpose is to make slide down catalog of Headings sections which will be as link to the goods page. Maybe there is allready solution of the developed catalog?

Comment: You're using PHP code so add PHP tags to your question.

Comment: There is no visual of what you want to create so it's really hard to understand what the desired result is. What do you mean by slide up or slide down?

Comment: You can see script by link - http://shopes.net/

Comment: I don't see any `<li>` tags in your code... why don't you take a template of a menu like that and then add your PHP algorithm to it?

Comment: I use Buttons group with Vertical variation - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-vertical and change CSS position from absolute to relative

Comment: If you're creating a navigation element there are a couple of reasons why using those buttons are bad practice. 1. Using `<div>` or `<button>` is not semantic, that's why we have the `<nav>` element. 2. You will have to consider responsiveness whereas in Bootstrap responsiveness is already taken into account with a navbar. 3. Using `role="group"` will confuse screen readers and will give a hard time for the visually impaired, you want to consider accessibility when making a website. So overall, I recommend using a navbar in order to achieve what you're looking for. Read next comment:

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default - You can see there's a dropdown so you can basically create the same thing and still have accessibility, semantics and good practice. All it takes is small modifications to your code. If you want to style the navbar you can do that easily with CSS.

Comment: I change code for navigation element - http://shopes.net/ but second level menu stil wont open like first one. Have I made my self clear?

Comment: Here is an example of how to implement a multi-level menu using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/4ScFz/400/

Comment: This is not what I need.